# Analysing the frequency of Job titles in a corpus

Tags: r, nlp

I have a set of data that contains brief job descriptions and job titles. I am trying to analyse this data to understand the frequency of job titles in the data.

The data looks a little like this:

| Name | Job |
| --- | --- |
| John | Digital Product Lead |
| Jane | Account Manager, Head of Workplace Experience |
| Bill | Executive Assistant at EY |
| Tom | Senior Recruiter, People Experience, Talent Branding #EX #DX |

Within the Job variable, there are strings we are not interested in.

One way I have analysed the data is to use simple NLP to create a data frame that contains a word and its frequency within the corpus. I have used the following R code:

```
text <- df$job

docs <- VCorpus(VectorSource(text))

docs <- docs %>%
  tm_map(removeNumbers) %>%
  tm_map(removePunctuation) %>%
  tm_map(stripWhitespace)

docs <- tm_map(docs, content_transformer(tolower))
docs <- tm_map(docs, removeWords, stopwords("english"))

dtm <- TermDocumentMatrix(docs) 
matrix <- as.matrix(dtm) 
words <- sort(rowSums(matrix),decreasing=TRUE) 
JobFreq <- data.frame(word = names(words),freq=words)
```

This returns data that looks like this:

| Word | Freq |
| --- | --- |
| Senior | 1656 |
| Analyst | 798 |

The returned data is close to what I am looking for, but these words become out of context due to the nature of most job titles.

Is there a way to insert a corpus of common job titles so that when two (or more) strings in the data match a job in the corpus, they are not tokenised and so are treated as one? And if so, how would I implement this using R?

Thanks

Comment: you would have to provide lists of jobs or qualifiers and manually classify based on the list.

Comment: If the jobs are separated by commas, you could just split on the commas before removing punctuation. The step that removes punctuation looks like it is removing an important delimiter

Comment: It would be nice to have a dataset to work with, look at the dput() function. It would also be nice to have a desired output example.

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems (rather than a table or screenshot for example). One way of doing is by using the `dput` function on the data or a subset of the data you are using, then pasting the output into your question. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg

Comment: Do you have a corpus of common job titles? Stack Overflow is for specific programming questions. If you are seeing sources of data this is the wrong place to ask for help. If you have questions about your data analysis, then maybe a place like [datascience.se] would be more appropriate.